# PDF Presenter Console is installed but invisible in Dash

Tags: unity-dash, pdf, console, ppc

I just installed PDF Presenter Console via the Ubuntu Software Center. The centre confirms that the program is installed, but I cannot see it in the installed applications in Dash. So I cannot open the program.
Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I am new to Ubuntu.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit, on an oldish HP Compaq 6720s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into its `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, it turns out that there is a line in the file:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

Which means the application is not meant to be called from the launcher: it is a command line tool. Also, in the file is a line:

```
Exec=pdf-presenter-console %f
```

Which means you can run it from a terminal window, by the command:

```
pdf-presenter-console [file]
```

Another way to run it is right-click on a `.pdf` file and choose: "open with"

[image]